# How to use Widevine DRM Encryption in an Ionic video player?

Tags: android, ios, encryption, ionic-framework

I am trying to use Bitmovin player for my Ionic video application to play encrypted content. But so far everything I've tried seems not to work.

It only plays on web browsers so far. Is it possible to use widevine DRM on Ionic Android/iOS applications? If so, how can I go about it?

Comment: Have the exact same problem, have you found a solution ? (With bitmovin or widevine)

Comment: No ive not found a solution. i guess it only works on Native Applications